# How do I use tensorflow 1.14.0 in a python package and run it in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

I want to run this python's [package](https://github.com/sjblim/rmsn_nips_2018) that use Tensorflow 1.14.0 in a docker container,
this is my dockerfile try:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3.6
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0
COPY . /rmsn_nips_2018
CMD bash test_rmsn.sh
```

and this is the err:

```
$ sudo docker run rp
bash: /rmsn_nips_2018/test_rmsn.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dot not need multistage build also it does nothing, **TensorFlow image comes with python.**

Also better to create `WORKDIR` and then execute the script.

You can use below Docker image and it should work.

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . . 
CMD bash rmsn_nips_2018/test_rmsn.sh
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works but it doesn't access the other directories. 'Commencing R-MSN Training...
1 - Fitting Propensity Networks
python: can't open file 'script_rnn_fit.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a permissions issue. try adding this before the CMD line:

```
RUN chmod -R +x /rmsn_nips_2018/test_rmsn.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add `WORKDIR` in your docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3.6
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0
COPY . /rmsn_nips_2018
WORKDIR /rmsn_nips_2018
CMD bash test_rmsn.sh
```

I checked it's work. Check please [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)